# Pipe output to terminal and file using tee from grep and sed pipe

Tags: bash, sed, grep, tee

I'm trying to get the output from a grep and sed pipe to go to the terminal and a text file.

Neither

```
grep -Filr "string1" * 2>&1 | tee ~/outputfile.txt | sed -i "s|string1|string2|g"
```

nor

```
grep -Filr "string1" * | sed -i "s|string1|string2|g" 2>&1 | tee ~/outputfile.txt
```

work. I get "sed: no input files" going to the terminal so sed is not getting the correct input. I just want to see and write out to a text file which files are modified from the search and replace. I know using `find` instead of `grep` would be more efficient since the search wouldn't be done twice, but I'm not sure how to output the file name using `find` and `sed` when there is a search hit.

EDIT:

Oops I forgot to include `xargs` in the code. It should have been:

```
grep -Filr "string1" * 2>&1 | tee ~/outputfile.txt | xargs sed -i "s|string1|string2|g"
```

and

```
grep -Filr "string1" * | xargs sed -i "s|string1|string2|g" 2>&1 | tee ~/outputfile.txt
```

To be clear, I'm looking for a solution that modifies the matched files with the search and replace, and then outputs the modified files' file names to the terminal and a log file.

Answer (score 3):

The `-i` option to `sed` is only useful when `sed` operates on a file, not on standard input. Drop it, and your first option is correct.

Comment: Removing the `-i` does output the file names to the terminal and the text file. However those files are not being modified with the search and replace.

Comment: Of course not. `sed` has no way of knowing where  the data on its standard input is coming from.

Comment: Doh! I messed this up. I meant to write `grep -Filr "string1" * | xargs sed -i "s|string1|string2|g" 2>&1 | tee ~/outputfile.txt` No wonder it wasn't working. But with `xargs` I don't get the file names outputted to the terminal nor the log file.

Comment: Ah, yes. In that case, you do want your first try, minus the `-i`. I misunderstood the goal.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a loop:

```
for i in `grep -lr string1 *`; do sed -i . 's/string1/string2/g' $i; echo $i >> ~/outputfile.txt; done
```

I'd advise against using the 'i' option for grep, because it would match files which the sed command won't actually modify.

You can do the same with `find` and `exec`, but that's a dangerous tool.

Comment: That's a good point about the case sensitivity. I also like the for loop idea.

Comment: In what way is find and exec dangerous?

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９: Have you ever executed `rm *` by mistake, or in the wrong place? How about `rm -r *`? The syntax of `rm` is pretty simple; `find-exec` can move, alter, rename or delete files (and more), and it has tricky syntax. *Do not point this at your face.*

Answer (score 0):

I almost forgot about this. I eventually went with a for loop in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $( grep -Flr "string1" * ); do
    sed -i "s|string1|string2|g" $i
    echo $i
    echo $i >> ~/outputfile.txt
done
```

I'm using the vertical pipe | as the separator, because I'm replacing URL paths with lots of forward slashes.

Thank you both for your help.